# Global variables not persisting from CLI command

Tags: go, command-line-interface

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
)

var tests []string

func main() {

    if len(os.Args[:]) > 1 {
        tests = append(tests, "test")
        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(len(tests)) + " tests")
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        tests = append(tests, "test")
        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(len(tests)) + " tests")
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8086", r)
}
```

When i access the program from localhost:8086 it works okay and i can see `len(tests)` increment when i refresh.

But when i access the program with `./test arg` command, `len(tests)` increments to 1 but then gets lost, so next time it says 1 and never goes any higher.

I thought that these two methods should also share the same `tests` value, but when i write to one, the other can't read it etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand why your program doesn't persist globals between program re-runs?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, i thought all the time the program is running, any method i use to access it will see the same global  variables.

Comment: Executing the program with arg or no arg always starts a new process with an empty tests slice and with no knowledge of other `./test` programs that might already be running. It will exit if an arg is given or listen on 8086 if no arg is given. If you want a cli to communicate with a server you need two programs and a strategy on how they gonna share data. One program with globals is not the way to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

`tests` is a global variable. As long as your process is running, it will keep its value.

However, when you run `./test arg`, this starts a new process, adds an element to `tests`, then exits. The next invocation of `./test arg` is a completely new process, it has no way of sharing information with the previous invocation.

The process running with `./test arg` is also completely different from the currently-running web server started with `./test`. Same thing: they share no state, they just happen to be the same binary.

If you want to persist something between invocations of a given program, you need to save the data somewhere (file, database, etc...).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. In my real project its an array of websocket connections, so not sure i can store those to file, i guess i'll have to trigger via http instead of cli.